# How to detect where front-facing camera placed on device?

Tags: android, camera

Is there any ways to detect where front-facing camera placed on Android device?

I think on cell phones it's always on top of it, near the headphone. But all tablets are different. I checked Asus Transformer, and front camera is on the side (on top if I hold it in landscape mode), but Samsung Galaxy Tab (first gen, Android 2.2) has camera on top of it, like all cell phones.

So is there way to check where front camera placed? Maybe I can do it with code, maybe there is a rule for devices? Like Android 2.x devices has it on top, and Android 3.x devices has on the side? Then what about Adnroid 4.x devices?

Comment: did you come up an alternative way to guess at the location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html

There are two constants you can check:

```
int CAMERA_FACING_BACK The facing of the camera is opposite to that of the screen.
int CAMERA_FACING_FRONT The facing of the camera is the same as that of the screen.
```

So I'm sorry - no way to check if it's at the side.

Answer (score 2):

Above API level 9

```
/**
  * @return true : Front facing camera is available. false : Front facing
  *         camera is not available.
  */
     private boolean isFrontCameraAvailable() {

      int cameraCount = 0;
      boolean isFrontCameraAvailable = false;
      cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

      while (cameraCount > 0) {
       CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
       cameraCount--;
       Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraCount, cameraInfo);


       if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        isFrontCameraAvailable = true;
        break;
       }

      }

      return isFrontCameraAvailable;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
Camera.getCameraInfo (int cameraId, Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo).
```

You can determine the number of cameras with

```
Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
```

The Camera.CameraInfo.facing field will either be  CAMERA_FACING_BACK or CAMERA_FACING_FRONT.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I don't need to determine number of cams. I need to know where front camera placed on device (on top or on side) if it exists.

Comment: I gave the API for the only camera position info that exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an API for this information.

I think your best option is a heuristic approach to look at the `Build` info and make a mapping for the positions you know
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

If the device/brand match for a Samsung Galaxy Tab then assume it is on top.

If they match for Asus Transformer then assume it is on the left.

If you find a device/brand you don't know log it and if you get enough people that use that device research where the camera is an update your code.