# How can I know the position of the camera on an android device?

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm building an Android application where I use the front camera for some image manipulation.

It's important for me to know where the camera is located. For example, on the Samsung S3 it's on the upper part of the device, where as on the Galaxy Note 10 - it's on the side.

It is important so I can know what is the orientation of the camera preview buffer and the orientation of the screen itself (I want to keep the UI always in portrait relative to the camera, i.e - so the camera is always on TOP).

Any ideas?

EDIT: I can use Android 4 and above (no need to support lower versions)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775872/how-to-detect-where-front-facing-camera-placed-on-device

Comment: Thanks - didn't see it :) Seems like 'orientation' can be manipulated to get the right info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as others said, the position itself doesn't matter as you just get the orientation etc etc.

Said that, I got this method from StackOverflow before (kudos for the guy that developed it) and it works like a charm. Just call it on your `surfaceCreated` callback.

```
    private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int degrees = 0;
            switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    degrees = 0;
                    break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    degrees = 90;
                    break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    degrees = 180;
                    break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    degrees = 270;
                    break;
            }

            int result;
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                    result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
            } else { // back-facing
                    result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the reference from android itself, I don't think there is a way to figure out where the camera is located on the device:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html