# Android Difficult Screen Orientation

Tags: android, screen, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

I have recently started studying Android, and I would, as first application, create my own camera. After taking a look at the API and other examples on the internet, I was able to create a working app, however I have this problem: if I rotate the tablet that I'm using to try what I do, my app rotates in the wrong way.
So, when I switch from portrait to landscape, the transition is successful and buttons rotate correctly, but what camera really sees is as if it were rotated 90 degrees more than it should.
All this unless I decide to set in my activity screenOrientation: landscape, because in this case the camera sees everything correctly, but the buttons remain fixed in one place, don't rotate with the rotation of the tablet.
I have a tablet with only front-facing camera.
What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

check this answer I gave some time ago, it does have a nice method to call to correctly set the camera orientation.

[How can I know the position of the camera on an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945360/how-can-i-know-the-position-of-the-camera-on-an-android-device/15945789#15945789)

and with that code you should let your activity rotate freely